# Transforming coordinates to a topocentric system using PROJ.4?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, proj, pyproj

I would like to transform coordinates (e.g. WGS84 or Bejing1954) to a topocentric system.

There seem to be several EPSG codes for this (5819, 5820, 5821, 15594, found [here](http://georepository.com/crs_5819/EPSG-topocentric-example-A.html) or [here](https://epsg.io/15594)) but none of them is working with PROJ.4

It just shows the message: `no options found in 'init' file`

I saw that it is possible to define a custom transformation in PROJ using several [parameters](http://proj4.org/parameters.html#parameter-list), but since I am not familiar with this I have no clue how to do it.

Is this possible at all? And i f yes, could someone help me to compile the correct set of parameters?

Comment: Looks like there is nothing build in. I assume first you can transform to geocentic parameters `proj=geocent` and then run transformation manually, see http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:method:EPSG::9837

Answer (score 3):

Currently it does not seem to be supported in PROJ. With the latest version, I used the `projinfo` command:

```
$ projinfo -s "WGS84" -t "epsg:5819"
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation n°1:

unknown id, Inverse of Null geographic offset from WGS 84 to WGS 84 + EPSG topocentric example A, 0 m, World

PROJ string:
Error when exporting to PROJ string: Unsupported conversion method: Geographic/topocentric conversions
```

The error `Unsupported conversion method: Geographic/topocentric conversions` seems to indicate that this is not supported at this time.

UPDATE: topocentric added in PROJ 8 (https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2444)